# Testing Swift code through Objective-C code in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, xctest

I am writing test cases (XCTestCases) for my project which is mixed up with Obj-C as well as Swift code.
I am able to write test cases for Objective C code in swift language.
But I am not able to access swift class in Objective C test files. It is showing compiler error.

1. I have imported    #import "MyProjectTests-Swift.h" file in my Objective C test file.
2. 'Enable testability' and 'Defines Module' is set to 'YES' for test target

Am I missing anything? When I open "MyProjectTests-Swift.h" file, I am not able to see Obj C generated declaration for Swift code.

My code

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import <OCMock/OCMock.h>
#import "MyProjectTests-Swift.h"


- (void)testExample {    
   MyController *myController= [[MyController alloc] init];
}
```

Error

```
1. Use of undeclared identifier 'MyController'
2. Use of undeclared identifier 'myController'
```

MyProjectTests-Swift.h  Code

```
// Generated by Apple Swift version 2.2 (swiftlang-703.0.18.8 clang-703.0.31)
#pragma clang diagnostic push

#if defined(__has_include) && __has_include(<swift/objc-prologue.h>)
# include <swift/objc-prologue.h>
#endif

#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wauto-import"
#include <objc/NSObject.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#if !defined(SWIFT_TYPEDEFS)
# define SWIFT_TYPEDEFS 1
# if defined(__has_include) && __has_include(<uchar.h>)
#  include <uchar.h>
# elif !defined(__cplusplus) || __cplusplus < 201103L
typedef uint_least16_t char16_t;
typedef uint_least32_t char32_t;
# endif
typedef float swift_float2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef float swift_float3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef float swift_float4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
typedef double swift_double2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef double swift_double3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef double swift_double4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
typedef int swift_int2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef int swift_int3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef int swift_int4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_PASTE)
# define SWIFT_PASTE_HELPER(x, y) x##y
# define SWIFT_PASTE(x, y) SWIFT_PASTE_HELPER(x, y)
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_METATYPE)
# define SWIFT_METATYPE(X) Class
#endif

#if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(objc_runtime_name)
# define SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(X) __attribute__((objc_runtime_name(X)))
#else
# define SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(X)
#endif
#if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(swift_name)
# define SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(X) __attribute__((swift_name(X)))
#else
# define SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(X)
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS)
# if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(objc_subclassing_restricted)
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) __attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted)) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#  define SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) __attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted)) SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# else
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#  define SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# endif
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_PROTOCOL)
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_EXTENSION)
# define SWIFT_EXTENSION(M) SWIFT_PASTE(M##_Swift_, __LINE__)
#endif

#if !defined(OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER)
# if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(objc_designated_initializer)
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER __attribute__((objc_designated_initializer))
# else
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
# endif
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_ENUM)
# define SWIFT_ENUM(_type, _name) enum _name : _type _name; enum SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA _name : _type
# if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(generalized_swift_name)
#  define SWIFT_ENUM_NAMED(_type, _name, SWIFT_NAME) enum _name : _type _name SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME); enum SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA _name : _type
# else
#  define SWIFT_ENUM_NAMED(_type, _name, SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_ENUM(_type, _name)
# endif
#endif
#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(modules)
#endif

#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wproperty-attribute-mismatch"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wduplicate-method-arg"
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

MyController Swift Class

```
import Foundation

class MyController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

// Project specific logic

}
```

Comment: What's the error? What's the code you're using?

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti, I have added code. As I mentioned I am not able to access  Swift class in Obj C file.

Comment: What's inside `MyProjectTests-Swift.h` ?

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti Added..... I guess it should have Objective C declaration of "MyController" class, but it is missing

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem. Bridging header was missing in test target (Swift Compiler - Code Generation -> Objective-C Bridging Header )
I just added it and build the project. Now MyProjectTests-Swift.h is showing all objective C generated header declarations.

Hope this will help if someone face the same problem.

Comment: I'm wondering why this was a problem to begin with. Does your bridging header have a special name, something other than _ProjectName_-Bridging-Header.h?

Answer (score 0):

Found this question looking for a related problem, for which I needed to do something else to fix it: When your app uses Swift and Objective-C, and your test target has mixed languages, too, then you will want to write this in your test files to access Swift types in your ObjC tests:

```
#import "AppName-Swift.h"
```

When that doesn't work for you, that's probably because **the test target cannot find the app target's generated header** out-of-the box.

### Solution

Add

```
$CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR/AppName.build/DerivedSources
```

to *Build Settings > Header Search Paths* of your test targets. Then your tests will be able to find the app's generated headers.